# Way to automatically check in code to Azure Repo as part of script

Tags: python, git, azure, azure-devops, version-control

I have a Python Script that alters and saves text files locally to my laptop, but I want a way to automate sending the files to an Azure Repository as part of the Script. I save the files locally because I figured I could use another script to send the code to the repo, which is still an option, but ideally if it could be part of the originally script that would work better. Could someone point me in the right direction to go about doing this?

Comment: An Azure Repository is just a Git repository from what I can see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/command-prompt?view=azure-devops); _surely_ there's already _tons_ of posts here, and on other sites, about how to commit/push files to a git repo from a Python script.

Answer (score 0):

- As Suggested by [Random Davis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6273251/random-davis). yes Azure Repo is a Git repository.
- While in Visual Studio, open a command prompt in your repo from Team Explorer's **Connect** view. Right-click your local repo and select **Open Command Prompt**

[image]

- For complete information check this [document](https://blog.thenetworknerd.com/2020/04/25/push-and-pull-using-vs-code-with-azure-repos/). and [Git Repository](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/command-prompt?view=azure-devops) Document.